# How to add ( and ) in Python result

Tags: python-3.x

I am new Python3 so for give me for asking such question but I couldn't find answer on Google, I have Python scanning a file directory and I need to add in an open and close bracket and a new var into the Python result, so that I can insert it into the database.

Mysql requires inserts to be wrapped in brackets  in the  **val =[('test.mp4',newip) ]**  This works as I get 1 was inserted when I run the hard coded script.

So what I am trying to archive is to modify the  result of the scan and add the following
open/close brackets and the new **newip** into the result of the scan like the following example

Scan result
**['test.mp4', 'test_2.mp4', 'test_3.mp4', test_4.mp4']**

Insert new result (modified)
**[('test',newip), ('test_2.mp4',newip), ('test_3.mp4',newip), ('test_4.mp4',newip)]**

When hard coded its works

```
root@ubuntu:~# python3 testscan.py
['test.mp4', 'test_2.mp4', 'test_3.mp4', test_4.mp4']
1 was inserted.
```

Please can anyone advise how to achieve this, below is the full code

```
import os, mysql.connector,  re, uuid
files  = [f.name for f in (os.scandir('/var/www/html/media/usb1')) if f.name.endswith('.mp4')]
print(files)

newip =  (':'.join(re.findall('..', '%012x' % uuid.getnode())))

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
  user="user",
  password="password",
  database="database"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO files (file,ip) VALUES (%s,%s)"
val =[('test.mp4',newip)]

mycursor.executemany(sql, val)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted.")
```

Comment: as is, you're code is missing an ending ```"``` after ```host="127.0.0.1,```

Comment: updated the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to add the newip to the scan you can use a list comprehension:

```
    files = ['test.mp4', 'test_2.mp4', 'test_3.mp4', 'test_4.mp4']

    sql_values = [(file, newip) for file in files]
```

the result looks like this:

```
    [('test.mp4', newip), ('test2.mp4', newip), ('test3.mp4', newip), ('test4.mp4', newip)]
```

Comment: Thank you, you've made it look so easy, was up all night trying to figure it out. 4 was inserted.

Comment: No problem dude. We learn from each challenge. We all started to code one time ago ^^